# stackoverflow error when converting hibernate object to json

Tags: java, json, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, stack-overflow

I have a user object with the following hibernate mapping which is a many to many self join:

```
    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="User" table="User">
            <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="userId" />
                <generator class="native" />
            </id>
            <set name="friends" table="User_Friend" 
                    inverse="false" lazy="true" cascade="all">
                <key column="userId"/>
                <many-to-many column="friendId" class="User" />
            </set>
            <set name="cars" table="Car" inverse="true" fetch="select" lazy="true">
            <key>
                <column name="userId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Car" />
        </set>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

The car mapping looks like the following:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Car" table="Car">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="carId" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <set name="carStatuses" table="Car_Status" 
                inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="carId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="CarStatus" />
        </set>
        <many-to-one name="user" 
        column="userId"
        not-null="true"/>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I retrieve the user object and then attempt to return it as a Restlet JSON Representation with this method:

```
public Representation getJSONRepresentationFromObject(User object) {


    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(object);

    ja.put(jo);

    JsonRepresentation jr = new JsonRepresentation(ja);
    jr.setCharacterSet(CharacterSet.UTF_8);

    return jr;
}
```

The problem is that I get a `StackOverflowError`:

> WARNING: Exception or error caught in resource
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError  at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:988)  at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:272)   at
>   org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1587)    at
>   org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:158)     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1569)    at
>   org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:990)  at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:272)   at
>   org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1587)    at
>   org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:158)     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.wrap(JSONObject.java:1569)    at
>   org.json.JSONObject.populateMap(JSONObject.java:990)  at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:272)

If I remove the cars set in the user mapping the error goes away and I am able to convert the user to json.  Is there something wrong with the car mapping that throws it into an infinite loop?

Comment: It might be the introspection of dynamically created objects by the JSON library that fails. You should try using the Jackson extension of Restlet to see if it works better

Comment: A user has cars, which have a user, which has cars, which have a user, which has cars, which have a user, etc. Hence the StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Car object has a back reference to the User/ Friend object.  I solved this problem here:

[Hibernate Object not detaching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965951/hibernate-object-not-detaching)

**Answer**: pull object from hibernate. Create separate java object. Loop through objects and populate newly created objects with hibernate object values.